# SQL tables with mutual reliances

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a couple of tables as follows:

[image]

Product: is a table containing products

ProductInterest: is a table that contains interest rate data. The table contains ProductID because each of the rates must be mapped to a product. The rates are then paired up with ProductDetail rows.

Relationship Key: ProductID

However I now have a scenario where I want to identify the primary rate for each product. As far as I can see I have 2 options (not necessarily both viable).

1) Add a primary rate bit to the ProductInterest table
2) Add a PrimaryInterestRateID to product. This of course creates a problem because of mutual dependencies.

Unfortunately I'm not that experienced with SQL so I'm struggling to decide whether there is an alternative to option 1, or whether I should just stick with it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I choose this:

**Add a primary rate bit to the ProductInterest** because in this case, you can work only on the secondary table. Functionally, this is an attribute of ProductInterest entity.

In other way **Add a PrimaryInterestRateID to product** you have a issue about foreign key constraint about a loop between two tables.

Answer (score 2):

> In other way Add a PrimaryInterestRateID to product you have a issue about foreign key constraint about a loop between two tables.
>   (Joe Taras)

To prevent the loop you can add a column **IsPrimary(bit)** to **ProductInterest** and remove the foreign key in **Product**.

**Edit:**

I had an similar problem in one of my databases and couldn't solve it with a flag so I changed the foreign key constraint option: **Enforce Foregin Key Constraint** from true to false and added ON UPDATE, DELET and INSERT triggers to both tables.

Comment: Unfortunately there are a number of rates per product so this wouldnt be possible.